# Initialize values in ViewModel with Proto Datastore on Jetpack Compose

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, protocol-buffers, android-viewmodel, kotlin-flow

I am trying to initialize `String` values in ViewModel and cannot find proper solutions for this situation. The intended operation is as follows:

1. There is a string value on ViewModel and real value on Proto Datastore.
2. Initialize a string value with existing value saved at Proto Datastore.
3. Change a string value on ViewModel. (NOT applying change to Proto Datastore in this step!)
4. If changing string value completed, request Proto Datastore to apply string values on real values.

```kotlin
class MainViewModel(private val repository: DataRepository) : ViewMode() {
    private val _stringValue = MutableStateFlow("") // trying to initialize this value

    fun setStringValue(value: String) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            repository.setStringValue(value)
        }
    }
}
```

```
message Data {
    string stringValue = 1;
}
```

I tried initializing string value on Composable, because currently I am using `Flow` and `Flow.collectAsState()` method is only avaliable on `@Composable` annotated function. But it has critical problem that when every recomposition happens, string value is initialized with unintended values, too.

So I changed the way and trying to initialize it on ViewModel. But cannot find proper way on Google to do this.